# Strange cascade behaviour Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have two entities

```
TB\Entity\UserProfile
/** 
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="TB\Entity\ShopVideo", mappedBy="shop",
 * cascade={"persist", "remove"}
 * )
 */
private $video;
```

and
TB\Entity\ShopVideo

```
/**
 * @var UserProfile
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="TB\Entity\UserProfile")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *   @JoinColumn(name="shop", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $shop;
```

If I create a UserProfile instance and a ShopVideo instance as so

```
    $profile = new TB\Entity\UserProfile();
    $model = new TB\Entity\ShopVideo();

    $profile->getShopVideo()->add($model);
    $this->_em->persist($profile);
    $this->_em->flush();
```

I would expect the 'shop' column to be populated with the id of the 'UserProfile' (and other models this has worked)... However I get the error (due to foreign key restraints)

PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'shop' cannot be null

```
/Users/ABCD/work/TB/TB/library/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php:131
/Users/ABCD/work/TB/TB/library/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php:226
/Users/ABCD/work/TB/TB/library/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:698
/Users/ABCD/work/TB/TB/library/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:280
/Users/ABCD/work/TB/TB/library/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:328
```

I just don't understand why the ShopVideo is not cascading the operation and setting the shop column with the id of the USerProfile? any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your @ManyToOne try adding inversedBy="video". This may or may not solve this issue, but it is a required property in the case of bidirectional associations.